# How to have 2 columns in google sheets auto multiply?

Tags: google-sheets

How do I go about setting up 2 entirely blank columns to automatically multiply their adjacent values and store it into a third column?

something like: `this.column = columnB.y * columbC.y`

Comment: If you have 2 columns `A` and `B`, and you want the multiplied value in column `C`, enter `=A1*B1` into the `C1` cell (don't forget the `=` sign). Then drag the bottom right corner of `C1` down to match the height of your `A/B` columns.

Comment: or `=A*B` Ctrl+Shift+Enter

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your input columns are A and B, try:

```
=ArrayFormula(if(A:A*B:B,A:A*B:B,""))
```